# Can't get Terminal Emulator for Android to build in Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator). I'm running Android Studio 1.4 in Kubuntu 15.04. I also tried building it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the same results. The project requires the latest Android NDK, SDK 22, and SDK 11 which I've downloaded and configured in Android Studio. My system gradle version is 2.8, and Android Studio has downloaded some other versions internally. I'm using jdk1.8.0_65, which is set to `JAVA_HOME` and configured in Android Studio. I've built several other projects with my configured Android Studio and only seem to have a problem with this project. I need to use this project as a base for an app I'm developing.

I end up with same error, posted below, no matter what route I take to fix it in Android Studio. This is generally what I've done to try and get the project to work. I open up the project unmodified in Android Studio. I click **Build >> Rebuild Project**. I get an error telling me ndk implementation is deprecated. I add a file `gradle.properties` to the root directory of the project with the line `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` and rebuild. It gives me an error: `Task 'generateDebugTestSources' not found in project`. I execute **Sync Project With Gradle Files** to resolve it. Then I end up with the following error and can't get past it.

> Gradle 'Android-Terminal-Emulator-master' project refresh failed
>     Error:exception during working with external system:

or

> Gradle sync failed: exception during working with external system: 
>      Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

[idea.log](http://chopapp.com/#q6holib1)

Things I've done to try and get the project to build:

- Modify all of the project's build.gradle files to use the experimental plugin
- Use different versions of Android Studio
- Switch from openjdk to Oracle's jdk
- Upgrade gradle to the latest version
- Set gradle to default wrapper (default) and also set gradle to different versions
- invalidate cache, remove ~/.gradle, and rebuild project
- Make sure PATH includes the gradle and jdk `bin` directories and is in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, and ~/.zshrc
- remove proguard from libtermexec library
- reboot computer

I should note that the project builds without issue on the command line. I'd really like to get the project to build in Android Studio for development.

Answer (score 0):

Install Arch and run Android Studio there.

I decided to try building Terminal Emulator on my Arch server, so I installed a xfce (Desktop Environment) and Android-Studio through pacman. I followed the same general path to get things setup, and the app built without issue.

The idea log Android Studio generated for the failed build on Windows and Ubuntu didn't point to any clear problem, even with `--stacktrace` enabled with gradle. I'm not going to waste my time figuring out why gradle doesn't want to build apps in Ubuntu or Windows.